# The property Date is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am getting the following error when i am creating a new object of my class. In my database, this tabel has 4 Pk's, namely, EmployeeId (int), ProjectId (int), Date (datetime) and Type (nvarchar).

When trying to insert a new record using EF and Respository I am getting this error. The error showed up when using the Insert method not even the Save method.

**EDIT:**
Also when I am trying to update other tables, I get the same error. I have the Date columns in multiple tables, I cant find which one gives me the error.

The property Date is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

Comment: The  error is obvious, hou cant modify it because its in a composite key

Comment: @Hassan Yes, but I am creating a new object, so i should be able to set the values as i want to?

Comment: reproduce it, i think canceling the date column as pk will fixes it and also causes no problem.

Comment: I tried to createa new object with the date = DateTime.Now. The problem still occured. When dbSet.Add(entity) is called, i get the exception. It is not an option to cancel the pk's in the database

Comment: When the error occured when inserting, I assume EF still assumes the key is autoincrement. disable this using HasDataBaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOptions.None);

Comment: @DevilSuichiro where can i do that and what happens when i update my model from database?

Comment: I found out that also creating and inserting another object gives me the same error about the Date column.

Comment: where can i do that - in your dbcontext, in your overridden OnModelCreating() function. you can use the call modelBuilder.Entity<EntityType>().Property(x=>x.ColumnName).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None); this will not skip your datetime column in the created insert statement.

Comment: what happens when i update my model from database - your model from DB? when you create your model from DB, you'll always get POCO classes exactly matching your tables, empty modelBuilder. when you update db from model however, it will not create this column with AUTOINCREMENT, IDENTITY... when your column still has autoincrement, you can disable this temporarily by using identity insert and wrapping your db calls in a transaction.